# Prove by contradiction that there no least positive rational number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My turn :
a)The error is that he considered the number $\frac{a-b}{b}$ as a positive rational number which is not necessary happens.
b)
let $n = \frac{a}{b}$ is the least positive rational number and let
$n_1 = \frac{c}{d}$ is a positive rational number smaller than n
$$n-n_1 = \frac{a}{b} -\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad -bc}{bd}$$
Since a , d , b , c are integers then $n -n_1$ is also rational number smaller than n 
Is the solution correct ? 
[image]

Comment: Isn't it a contradiction to define $n_1 < n$ after you assumed $n$ was the smallest rational number?

Comment: Yes the error is that $n-1$ may not be positive. However the logic in your own proof is suspect. You assumed that there is a least positive rational and then in the every next line you assumed that there was a smaller one.

Comment: Easier: just take $n/2$.

Comment: Just take $n/2$. It is rational, positive and smaller than $n$.

Comment: Your proof will work if you define $c=a$ and $d=2b$.